# How to calculate assortativity for the vertex with multiple values in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to calculate assortativity by a vertex label like group, which has multiple value:
I know how to calculate assortativity.nominal  based on the label vertex like gender,

```
assortativity.nominal(graph,types=factor(V(graph[[g]])$gender),directed=TRUE)
```

but How to calculate for labels like group or education ?

```
vertex  group                               education
  1      ["1105460"]                        ["1105460"]                  
  2      ["2301561","278628"]               ["2301561","278628"]
  3      ["6002301","1105460","1382948"]    ["6002301","1105460","1382948"]   
  4      ["6002301","278628","1105460"]     ["6002301","278628","1105460"]
```

Comment: What is `group`? If it is a factor, then you can do it the same way as for `gender`.

Comment: @  Gabor Csardi : please see the edit .

Comment: So how is assortativity defined in this case?

Comment: @GaborCsardi : I have problem defining it.but, I guess,the similarity will be defined on the number of group two vertex share, what is your idea?

Comment: For the original definition, for each vertex you need to define a group, not a similarity. Maybe there is an extension for overlapping groups, which seems to be your case, I don't know.

Comment: thanks @GaborCsardi for your comment, I meant when we say assortativity_is a preference for a network's nodes to attach to others that are similar in some way_this similarity is on the number of the education or group they share and each vertex has multiple rather than one value like gender.is this a new case ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have said: I am not sure if it is defined for overlapping groups. Maybe you can define it in some reasonable way. But this is not implemented in igraph.

Comment: thanks @GaborCsardi for assuring me, it may be off topic here but what would this kind of homophily called, I searched for a couple of things like assortativity for vertex with multiple value type , with multiple label but it wasn't  successful do you have any suggestion?